# How do I reorder tags in MarketDataRequest message?

Tags: vb.net, quickfix

I'm trying to subscribe to a price stream, using the following code:

```
Using l_msg As New QuickFix42.MarketDataRequest(New MDReqID(Date.Now.Ticks.ToString), New SubscriptionRequestType(SubscriptionRequestType.SNAPSHOT_PLUS_UPDATES), New MarketDepth(1))

            l_msg.setField(New MDUpdateType(1))
            l_msg.setField(New AggregatedBook(False))
            l_msg.setField(New NoMDEntryTypes(2))
            l_msg.setField(New MDEntryType("0"c))
            l_msg.setField(New MDEntryType("1"c))
            l_msg.setField(New Symbol("EUR/USD"))
            l_msg.setField(New NoRelatedSym(1))

            Session.sendToTarget(l_msg, SENDER_COMP_ID.Value, TARGET_COMP_ID.Value)
        End Using
```

The produced FIX message is:

> 8=FIX.4.2 9=140 35=V 34=2 49=SENDER_COMP_ID 52=20110909-15:44:02.855
>   56=TARGET_COMP_ID 55=EUR/USD 146=1 262=634511906383686907 263=1 264=1
>   265=1 266=N 267=2 269=1 10=079

I need to reorder the tags so 55 comes right after tag 146.
I tried invoking `setField` in different order, but it gives the same result every time.

What is the correct way of handling message tag order?

**Edit - problem resolved:**

I followed [DumbCoder suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391049/how-do-i-reorder-tags-in-marketdatarequest-message/7399246#comment9006343_7399246) and build the message by using `addGroup` instead of `setField`. The following code sample helped me as well:
http://forexforums.dailyfx.com/fix-api-support/411090-fix-api-example.html

Note: The sample is written in Java and targets QF44.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK quickfix uses a map to read tags and then populate their values, so the placement of the tags is language decided and not by the library.

Set *ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder as N* on your acceptor, so even if the tags are out of order your message isn't rejected. This caused a lot of work for me, because whatever I tried the tags were never in orer and I had to relent on putting tags in order. And an acceptor which rejects messages if tags aren't in order isn't a good option. You cannot rely on every fix library to do your bidding.

Comment: Thanks @DumbCoder, my FIX account is currently offline so i can't test it. Meanwhile can you please clarify the following: As far as i know, i'm only the _initiator_, and my config file specifies settings for the _initiator_. How can I set _ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder_ on my _acceptor_ (which i believe is the broker side right?)

Comment: @MichaelS - Does the acceptor rejects your FIX message ? If no why do you care ? If yes, does your broker deals only with you or multiple clients ? And which FIX engine does your broker run ? And sorry should have made it more clearer that ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder has to be on the acceptor side, not on the initiator side.

Comment: yes my message is being rejected and the support specified that _"the ordering of the tags was not correct"_ and tag 55 must come right after 146. My broker has many other clients, and I know that _Currenex_ is their provider. I have no idea on which FIX engine they use. What should I do next?

Comment: @MichaelS - That is bollocks. Ok do this. Don't do, add a single field, **l_msg.setField(New MDEntryType("0"c))** but add the whole group. Doesn't matter if only one field is present, use addGroup rather than setField.

Comment: The funny thing is that FIX requires only few fields to be in certain places. The order of most of the fields is not specified by the standard.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko - Standard doesn't want the fields to be in order, but the engines require it to make processing faster.

Comment: @DumbCoder: BS. It doesn't make processing any faster. There is no engine where it could potentially help. Neither open source nor proprietary. I've wrote a FIX engine for HFT firm so I know what I am saying.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko - Don't need to be a jackass and start throwing expletives at others. Try telling this to the Quickfix guys.

Comment: @DumbCoder: Check out QF latency report here - http://lazarenko.me/reviews/programming-languages-in-high-frequency-trading  ... I told those guys already that they suck :)